# String.replace in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I need to convert this string

```
"/{foo}/{bar}.{format}"
```

in

```
"/#{a["foo"]}/#{a["bar"]}.#{a["format"]}"
```

Because I have a list with these attributes.
for instance

```
a["foo"] = "home"
a["bar"] = "picture"
a["format"] = "jpg"
```

I try to something like this

```
String.replace(a,"{",~s(#{))
```

But I got this error (

> SyntaxError) iex:8: unexpected token: )

I try even a regexp to create a List to try to have my result but I don't understand how can I apply this regexp `([^{]*?)\w(?=\})`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you want the string `"/home/picture.jpg"` as the result, you can use `Regex.replace/3` with a function as replacement:

```
map = %{
  "foo" => "home",
  "bar" => "picture",
  "format" => "jpg",
}

string = "/{foo}/{bar}.{format}"

Regex.replace(~r/{([a-z]+)?}/, string, fn _, match ->
  map[match]
end)
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
"/home/picture.jpg"
```

Answer (score 6):

Use capital `S` in sigil:

```
iex> a = "/{foo}/{bar}.{format}"
iex> IO.puts String.replace(a,"{",~S(#{))
/#{foo}/#{bar}.#{format}
```

Sigils are explained here: https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/sigils.html#interpolation-and-escaping-in-sigils